# checking existing username is not working

Tags: php, mysql

im at lost here. pls help. tqvm. theres no problem with registering but it still add even when the username already exist. tq again.

1.register.php

```
<?php 

require "conn.php";

$name = "123";
$username = "bob";
$password = "!23";
$role = "123";

$checkdata=" SELECT username FROM employee_data WHERE username='$username'  ";

$query=mysql_query($checkdata);

if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
{
echo "User Name Already Exist";
}

else{
$mysql_qry = "insert into  employee_data (name, username, password, role)   values ('$name', '$username', '$password', '$role')";
if($conn->query($mysql_qry) === TRUE){

    echo "Success Registration";
}
else {
    echo "Fail Registration";
}
}


$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: please refrain from mysql_ functions as they are deprecated, and in PHP7 removed. use mysqli_ or PDO instead. and learn about SQL Injections, your code is very vulnerable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about the $conn instance. I am not founding, where you have created the instance. So I removed the $conn. Try this,

```
require "conn.php";
$name = "123";
$username = "bob";
$password = "!23";
$role = "123";

$checkdata="SELECT username 
              FROM employee_data 
             WHERE username='$username'  ";
$query = mysql_query($checkdata);
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0) {
    echo "User Name Already Exist";
} else {
    $mysql_qry = "insert into  employee_data (name, username, password, role)   values ('$name', '$username', '$password', '$role')";
    $store = mysql_query($mysql_qry);
    if($store){
        echo "Success Registration";
    } else {
        echo "Fail Registration";
    }
}

?>
```

## USING PDO

```
<?php 

$host = "";     # Host name
$dbName = "";   # Database name
$userName = ""; # user name to thye host
$password = ""  # password to the host

$pdoHandler = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbName.';';
$pdo = new PDO($pdoHandler, $userName, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$name = "123";
$username = "bob";
$password = "!23";
$role = "123";

try {

    $checkdata="SELECT username 
                  FROM employee_data 
                 WHERE username=?";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($checkdata);
    $query->execute(array($username));
    $userExist = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($userExist) {
        echo "User Name Already Exist";
    } else {
        $mysql_qry = "INSERT INTO employee_data(name, username, password, role)
                             VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $store = $pdo->prepare($mysql_qry);
        $store->execute(array($name, $username, $password, $role));
        if($store){
            echo "Success Registration";
        } else {
            echo "Fail Registration";
        }
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "SQL Error: ".$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: This is not what he asked for.

Comment: Read question carefully.

Comment: @Dinesh Patra $conn is the one that ive set inside conn.php [[$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name)]]. i thought that when running a query we need to include the connection? so ive tried removing and use $store as you mention but now it goes to "Fail Registration". any idea for this?

Comment: @Mr. Engineer, In the code I am not founding where he has intialized the $conn variable. So I have removed the $conn, and wrote mysql_query, Then what's wrong in that ?

Comment: @Atif, ya I got it, let me check.

Comment: @DineshPatra He just want to know how he can insert data if it's already present in database.

Comment: @Atif please try $store = mysql_query($mysql_qry) or die(mysql_error()); If there is any error, in your query you will get

Comment: @DineshPatra so i got this, Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Arip\register.php on line 50
No database selected

Comment: I think there is any query synatx in $checkdata. please try the mysql_error();   

$query = mysql_query($checkdata) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @ArifSam please check also with PDO I have updated. Just change the host name, userName and password.

Comment: @DineshPatra now it says no database selected. im really sorry for pestering you like this. really new to programming. tqvm though.

Comment: @Arif, it's okay, No problem. By the way which method you are trying? pdo or mysql ?

Comment: @DineshPatra now ive got it working. tqvm again. i just heard and seen pdo stuff from you. i havent heard of it before. got a lot more to learn.

Comment: you are most wel come. Try this blog to get introduction about pdo, http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-querying-data-from-mysql-table/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require "connection.php";

$name = "123";
$username = "foo";
$password = "!23";
$role = "123";

$checkdata="SELECT username FROM employee_data WHERE username='{$username}'";

$query=mysql_query($checkdata) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0) {
    echo "User Name Already Exist";
} else {
    echo "ok"; // registration code here
}
?>
```

try this one

Comment: same for me, I do not understand why they are not mentioning the reason for downvote. Simply coming and downvote .